# Typescript using "call" caused "this" type error

Tags: javascript, typescript, this

Having this `getCurrentTime` function:

```
const getCurrentTime = () => {
  const date = new Date();
  const d = Date.prototype;
  const funcs = [
    d.getFullYear,
    function() {
      return d.getMonth.call(this) + 1;
    },
    d.getDate,
    d.getHours,
    d.getMinutes,
  ];
  return funcs.reduce(
    (prevStr, current) => `${prevStr}-${current.call(date)}`,
    '',
  );
};
```

Raised an error: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation

I tried

`return d.getMonth.call<Date, any[], number>(this as Date) + 1;`

`return d.getMonth.call(this as Date) + 1;`

Neither worked, how can I fix this error

Comment: Wouldn't it be MUCH easier to have an array of values, rather than an array of functions? Also maybe not even `reduce` them but just format directly? This seems very roundabout and I'm not sure fixing the context issue would be worth it, rather than doing differently.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `getMonth` in a function? This might be unnecessary, or use an arrow function instead to maintain the `this` scope.

Comment: @JoostMeijer using arrow functions will cause `this` hoist up

Comment: @VLAZ you mean `date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getHours(), date.getMInutes()`, then `reduce`? I think it is less elegant, how about there is ten functions to be reduced.

Comment: @JoostMeijer because `date.getMonth()` starts from zero

Comment: @crazyones110 I don't think `.reduce` is in any way elegant here when what you're doing a very complex reimplementation of  `[ date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth.call(this) + 1, date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes() ].join("-");`

Comment: This seems like complexity for complexity's sake, this could be done with a single template literal, instead of an array+loop.

Comment: @VLAZ fair enough, I've updated my code. But is there a simple way to type annotate `this` in this scenario

Comment: [`function(this: Date) {}` will annotate the context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments that simply doing `date.getMonth() + 1` would be better.

As for the actual TypeScript error, though, adding explicit typing for `this` helps and can be done similarly to explicit argument types

```js
function(this: Date) {
  return d.getMonth.call(this) + 1;
}
```

["this parameters" in docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters)